# Changing borderstyle on mouse enter event

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to change the borderstyle of a picturebox on mouse enter event. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Try to use Mouse events (MouseHover, MouseUp, MOuseMove)

Comment: Override MouseEnter event for the picture and change the border there.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution, thank you.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        }
```